# $Q$ number equal to 0

Tags: nuclear-physics, mass-energy, binding-energy

What would $Q$ number equal to zero tell us about how the reaction occurs since $Q<0$ means energy needs to be supplied and $Q>0$ meaning the reaction occurs spontaneously. E.g. does $Q=0$ mean that the reaction is not energetically forbidden and can occur.

Comment: Some more context for your question might be helpful. Is $Q$ heat supplied to the system? Is $Q$ heat supplied by the system?

Comment: Q = (M_initial - M_final).c^2 for like beta decay the difference in mass of the initial and final state times c^2